# Slack API slash commands and interactive components modal

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I'm trying to make a bot in slack. I created a slash command with /showmodal, when the command triggered my api return this json

```
{
"type": "modal",
"title": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "My App",
    "emoji": true
},
"submit": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Submit",
    "emoji": true
},
"close": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Cancel",
    "emoji": true
},
"blocks": [
    {
        "type": "input",
        "element": {
            "type": "plain_text_input",
            "multiline": true
        },
        "label": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Label",
            "emoji": true
        }
    }
]}
```

I'm expecting this result

[image]

But I'm getting this response instead of the modal

/showmodal failed with the error "invalid_blocks"

Comment: are you using views.open ?

Comment: @CalebNjiiri Yes, I already solved it, trigger_id and view property is missing

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem by reading the documentation I forgot the include the trigger_id and view property

See the correct payload below

> {
>     "trigger_id": "TriggerIdFromRequestPayload",
>     "view": {
>       "type": "modal",
>       "callback_id": "modal-identifier",
>       "title": {
>         "type": "plain_text",
>         "text": "New Post"
>       },
>       "submit": {
>         "type": "plain_text",
>         "text": "Submit",
>         "emoji": true
>       },
>       "close": {
>         "type": "plain_text",
>         "text": "Cancel",
>         "emoji": true
>       },
>       "blocks": [
>         {
>           "type": "input",
>           "element": {
>             "type": "plain_text_input",
>             "action_id": "title",
>             "placeholder": {
>               "type": "plain_text",
>               "text": "Input title"
>             }
>           },
>           "label": {
>             "type": "plain_text",
>             "text": "Title"
>           }
>         },
>         {
>           "type": "input",
>           "element": {
>             "type": "plain_text_input",
>             "multiline": true
>           },
>           "label": {
>             "type": "plain_text",
>             "text": "Content",
>             "emoji": true
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }